# Dailymotion API : How to access private videos seamlessly

Tags: video, dailymotion-api

I would like to access a user private videos from my website.
The user must not know the login / password of the Dailymotion account. The transaction should be transparent to him

I looked at the API documentation:

http://www.dailymotion.com/doc/api/authentication.html
It says the user is redirected to an authentication form.

Is there a way to avoid it, and pass all required information in HTTP requests directly?

Answer (score 0):

If the information is passed through HTTP requests on the client side, then it's not transparent and anyone could easily extract private information from the request. What you could do is, if that user you're talking about is yours, then make the API calls server-side to retrieve the information you need securely. But you do understand that a private video is not a video you're supposed to embed publicly on a website right? If you do that, it becomes a public video again since everyone will be able to retrieve the private URL without effort.

Comment: make the API calls server-side: I don't think it is possible to do that with dailymotion JS API